# makefile loop variable

Tags: bash, loops, makefile, gnu

I have the following in the makefile:

```
RESULT=ab
nums:
    number=1 ; while [[ $$number -le $(DIRS_NUM) ]] ; do \

        now=`echo $(CURR_DIR) | cut -d "/" -f 1-$$number` ;\

        **RESULT = $$now;\**

        echo $(RESULT);\

        ((number = number + 1)) ; \    
    done
```

I would like to update the `RESULT` variable, but I'm not sure of how to do this.

Comment: Why? What else do you plan to do with `RESULT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update a makefile variable from within a rule. You could use the $(shell cmd) macro to execute a command and get a value out of its output stream, but that's about as close as you can come. A simple example:

```
X := $(shell echo 5)
```

Now `X` will have the value `5`.

Note the use of `:=` here, rather than a simple `=`. This expands everything on the right side immediately, rather than each time `X` is referenced.